# Cannot run Update-Manager 1:18.04.11.10 + Segmentation fault

Tags: command-line, update-manager, ld

I updated some packages + to kernel 4.15.0-52-generic in Ubuntu-Mate.

After that I can't open the "Update-Manager + software-properties-gtk" anymore.

Terminal Output:
Segmentation fault

Kern.log:

> Jun 24 17:29:35 user1 kernel: [ 3571.244993] update-manager[14392]:
>   segfault at b0 ip 00007f2f39904ac8 sp 00007f2f0f64e880 error 4 in
>   ld-2.27.so[7f2f398f8000+27000] "ld-2.27.so"

I have started a post here, but anyone can't help me to fix that error.

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cant-update-upgrade-anymore-um-18-04-v2-lts/19745/19

How can I fix that?
Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Crash.log there.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1834055

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly the same problem. and it was caused by extra OpenSSL library (libssl.so) in the /usr/local/lib.

Comment: ...how do you fix that? Install OpenSSL updates? Which packages?

Comment: @green-world i got source code (it was version 1.1.0g in my case) and 'sudo make uninstall'

Comment: @ Denis, I have installed: "OpenSSL 1.1.1b"

Comment: @green-world you mean system-wide package? you need to check /usr/local/lib directory. if you can find there libcrypto.so and/or libssl.so - it's a cause of the problem (actually in any case it's a problem with OpenSSL installation)

Comment: Yes, system-wide. I compiled OpenSSL 1.1.1b and instlled it to /usr/local/ssl.

Comment: How can I remove the compiled installed OpenSSL? Should I do it via Synaptic and replace OpenSSL?

Comment: in the root of OpenSSL source directory: sudo make uninstall

Comment: Done... I revert to Ubuntu OpenSSL packages back, but... 
my hardware has no bugs, another kernel has no success. It still appears segmentation fault when I call Terminal Update Manager.

Comment: update-manager[7108]: segfault at b0 ip 00007fafcd95cac8 sp 00007fafa36ba880 error 4 in ld-2.27.so

Comment: aptd[7110]: segfault at b0 ip 00007faf18f7cac8 sp 00007fffaf7dcce0 error 4 in ld-2.27.so[7faf18f70000+27000]

Comment: you can try this command to confirm it's an OpenSSL problem:
'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa'.
if you get 'SSL support not available' - it's a conflicting OpenSSL libs

Comment: I tested it, OpenSSL error.

Comment: See my third answer top above, to see the OpenSSL errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
[sudo] password for user:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 326, in get_ppa_info
ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 101, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 95, in get_info_from_lp
return get_info_from_https(lp_url, True)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_https
data = _get_https_content_py3(url, accept_json)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in _get_https_content_py3
lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 210, in urlopen
raise ValueError('SSL support not available')
ValueError: SSL support not available

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 136, in 
shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 868, in shortcut_handler
ret = factory(shortcut)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 398, in shortcut_handler
return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 355, in init
info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 338, in get_ppa_info
_get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 295, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 95, in get_info_from_lp
return get_info_from_https(lp_url, True)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_https
data = _get_https_content_py3(url, accept_json)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in _get_https_content_py3
lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 210, in urlopen
raise ValueError('SSL support not available')
ValueError: SSL support not available

> Installed OpenSSL packages:
>
```

> libevent-openssl-2.1-6 (2.1.8-stable-4build1) libgnutls-openssl27
>   (3.5.18-1ubuntu1.1) openssl (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.3)
>   perl-openssl-defaults (3build1) python-openssl (17.5.0-1ubuntu1)
>   python3-openssl (17.5.0-1ubuntu1) libssl-dev
>   (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.3) libssl-doc (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.3)
>   libssl1.0.0 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3) libssl1.1 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.3)

Do I need package?

openssl1.0 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3)

> ## openssl version

OpenSSL 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019

> ## which openssl

/usr/local/bin/openssl

> ## openssl speed (is working)

Doing mdc2 for 3s on 16 size blocks: 2371743 mdc2's in 2.99s
Doing mdc2 for 3s on 64 size blocks: 654173 mdc2's in 3.00s
Doing mdc2 for 3s on 256 size blocks: 167583 mdc2's in 3.00s
...

I don't know what is wrong with my OpenSSL.

Comment: (SOLVED) It was a OpenSSL problem. Removed old traces of old compiled OpenSSL and re-installed OpenSSL. apt-get install --reinstall openssl
apt-get install --reinstall libssl1.1

Comment: Here's the full thread of this problem and how I get it solved. https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cant-update-upgrade-anymore-um-18-04-v2-lts/19745/42